# Getting Sync of this section is not supported. Detailed error information: Getting Section, code 20258

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I have an app to which users can authorize and we can access the pages or sections of the user. I have setup the scopes and no problem with the scopes.

For some users, when we try to get pages for the user, we get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "20258",
        "message": "Sync of this section is not supported. Detailed error information: Getting Section",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-03-16T07:47:34",
            "request-id": "----",
            "client-request-id": "----"
        }
    }
}
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398292/onenote-api-fails-with-code-20258-graphclient-usersuserprincipalname-onenote) with same problem but it's difficult to find the section for all users and remove them(We actually can't remove them). Have to find a generic solution.

When I try to get the sections:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-03-16T07:48:55",
            "request-id": "---",
            "client-request-id": "---"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!